# Codeigniter 3.x / $config['time_reference'] = 'gmt' does not work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

In CI3, I have changed the config.php file to:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

I then do the following in a controller:

```
$this->data['mydate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Doing the above, I would expect it to equal the value of GMT as set in the config.php file, however, it comes out with a timezone which I don't know where it picks it up from.

Any ideas, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's `time_reference` config is only used for [`now()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/date_helper.php#L63) helper, nothing else.

To get time in GMT format you can use PHP's built-in function [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php):

```
$this->data['mydate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Thank you.  It was overly clear to me that it only applied to now().  Thank you and all working well now!